# Need to localize numbers in Google Visualization's vAxis

Tags: localization, google-visualization

I've set up a Google Visualization in an app, but I'm having trouble with formatting for localization. For the moment I'm trying to do two very simple things: define characters for thousands and decimal separators (override the ',' and '.' defaults, respectively).

This is very easy to do for the actual numbers which are displayed as tooltips, using NumberFormat:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
    {
        prefix: '$',
        decimalSymbol: ',',
        groupingSymbol: '.'
    }
);
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

But when it comes to formatting the actual axes, I'm lost. Here's the relevant bit:

```
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('costs_timeline')).
    draw(data,
    {
        vAxis: {format: "$#,###.00", minValue: 0},
    }
);
```

But the ',' and '.' characters cannot be replaced by their localized equivalents, because they are special characters with embedded meaning according to the [ICU docs](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details).

Has anyone ever succeeded with this before?